# Shell Script Search and Delete Non Text Files

Tags: scripting

I want to write a shell script to search and delete all non text files in a directory..

I basically cd into the directory that I want to iterate through in the script and search through all files.

-- Here is the part I can't do --

I want to check using an if statement if the file is a text file.
If not I want to delete it
else continue

Thanks

PS By the way this is in linux

### EDIT

I assume a file is a "text file" if and only if its name matches the shell pattern `*.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

The `file` program always outputs the word "text" when passed the name of a file that it determines contains text format. You can test for output using grep. For example:

```
find -type f -exec file '{}' \; | grep -v '.*:[[:space:]].*text.*' | cut -d ':' -f 1
```

I strongly recommend printing out files to delete before deleting them, to the point of redirecting output to a file and then doing:

```
rm $(<filename)
```

after reviewing the contents of "filename". And beware of filenames with spaces, if you have those, things can get more involved.

Comment: +1 for the file cmd - as a better way to determine if a file is not a binary file

Comment: rm $(<filename) will not work with all shells.  It is more portable to do something like: while read f; do rm $f; done < filenames

Comment: Life is too short to suffer inferior tools in the name of portability when bash can be had everywhere it matters. In short: I don't give a damn.

Comment: So a (hypothetical) POSIX compliant shell which executes 100 times faster than bash and consumes a smaller memory footprint but fails to support this one trivial and mostly useless feature is 'inferior'?  bash is not always available and not always desirable.  A competent developer understands what code constructs artificially limit the usability of code, and avoids them when possible.  This is one such instance.

Comment: If the script is too slow, I'll rewrite it in C or C# (mono also running on all the platforms I care about).

Comment: FWIW, if I had to deal with file spaces, I would do `while read -r f; do rm "$f"; done < filename`, but I wasn't, so I didn't.

Comment: Will you re-write all of your configure scripts in C?  One of the main motivations for trying to make /bin/sh be dash on debian was to speed up configure runs.  The tag for this question is 'scripting', not 'bash'.  An answer that relies on a bashism should at least explictly mention that limitation.

Comment: I wouldn't touch autotools / autoconf with a 10 foot pole. This comment section is going nowhere though, consider it duly noted that I used a bashism and more portable alternatives have been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the opposite of, unless an if statement is mandatory:

```
find <dir-path> -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} \;
```

What the opposite is exactly is an exercise for you. Hint: it comes before -name.

Your question was ambiguous about how you define a "text file", I assume it's just a file with extension ".txt" here.

Comment: So yes, anything with a .txt. Sorry for not clarifying... I guess I tried using the commands but I kept getting arguments too long when I tried it. This is why I tried iterating through all the files and checking

Comment: Updated my answer with *correct* syntax (oops!) for -exec. There's still one thing missing from the command to find everything that *isn't* a .txt file, which a quick Google or man find will help you find.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.txt" -exec rm {} +;
```